# Listview not populating after page navigation in Xamarin

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, hybrid

I have `ListView` defined in xaml as below:

```
<ListView x:Name="Iv" ItemSelected="Iv_ItemSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding deviceListEx}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This does work in first page load, however in iOS platform when I navigate to another page then back to the listview page by clicking back button, the page is blank, means listview is not populating.

Application is in c# and working fine in android.

Have anyone faced such issue or similar issue? Do let me know how can I solve this.

This is the code behind. The listview item source is the result of a bluetooth scan and it is a `ObservableCollection<string>`.

```
deviceList.Clear();
deviceListEx.Clear();
var scanner = CrossBleAdapter.Current.ScanWhenAdapterReady().
Subscribe(ScanResult =>
{     
   if (ScanResult.Device.Name != null)
       {
          deviceList.Add(ScanResult.Device);                             
          deviceListEx.Add(ScanResult.Device.Name.ToString());
          // unique bluetooth devices with name to listview
          Iv.ItemsSource = deviceListEx.Distinct();
           }          

    });
```

Comment: Does the issues appear in android ? Can you post the code behing and the item source that you are using

Comment: Not in android. Only in ios platform. Posted the C# code that I am using for populating the listview. Please have a look

Comment: Strange, seems to be correct. You can fix this if you populate your ListView in Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnAppearing method

Comment: Tried what you suggest. But not helped me to get rid of this issue :(

Comment: This is strange... Is on appearing method called when you back to it ? You should look about LifeCycle Page documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle

Comment: Is on appearing method called when you back to it ? - Yes. Also `deviceListEx` contains elements.

Comment: check if `deviceListEx.Clear();` is executed elsewhere.